# Spark SQL - JAVA syntax of CASE-THEN?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I noticed I can use CASE-THEN with Spark if I use an `SQLContext` and the `.sql()` function. Is there a way to use this in a JAVA syntax, directly on dataframes, too? How?
Now, I write:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(ctx);
DataFrame df = //some imported data 
df.registerTempTable("df");
sqlContext.sql("SELECT *use case-then in here* FROM df");
```

I'm looking for something like

```
df.select(case("this").then("that"));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just import `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` then use `when(Column col, Object obj)`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

df.select(functions.when(df.col("colName").equalTo("this"), "that").otherwise("something"));
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, as I wrote in the question :) I left out the step of registering the temp table, sorry. Updated now. I'm interested whether this has a JAVA syntax equvalent. :)

Comment: Can you also chain these whens, like: `df.select(functions.when(df.col("colName").equalTo("this"), "that"). when(df.col("colName").equalTo("somethingelse"), "dosomething").otherwise("something"));` ?